# how to run cgi scripts within django server

Tags: python, django, cgi

im using django 1.9. im new to django. i had tried many solutions but i didn't find right answer. like in this post [Django - routing to non-django script? (e.g. simple WSGI/CGI application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664678/django-routing-to-non-django-script-e-g-simple-wsgi-cgi-application)   we can redirect normal django request to non-django scripts. but the thing is we cant redirect with post parameters. tell me if is there any way to run CGI scripts within django server or not? if yes, please help me out..

Comment: you can't redirect with post data no matter what the server side technology is

Comment: @DanielRoseman we are integrating paytm(online payment ) to our website. for that they provided some code (cgi scripts ) for doing transactions. so we want to integrate that code to our django server.

Comment: Whatever CGI scripts they supplied you with are just examples. Looks like they have a full API which is documented [here](http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/) and also mention a Python SDK. You should use that API client to write the integration in Django.